# Filter Object Array

Tags: javascript, filter

This is the code:

```
var displayedYearDataCo2 = getYearFromObjectArray(dumpObjectArray);

var dumpObjectArray = [{
2000: "3861703.86265837",
2001: "3948395.50088809",
2002: "4079614.75274644",
2003: "4243914.23578233",
2004: "4473182.3714518",
2005: "4666976.64129297",
2006: "4912930.11306349",
2007: "5230542.3962404",
2008: "5447541.9024238",
2009: "5614275.08094141",
2010: "5873859.25045115"},
{2000: "6445883.82450361",
2001: "6500776.94950847",
2002: "6510827.66224668",
2003: "6702943.57911293",
2004: "6732003.46639188",
2005: "6712282.82564533",
2006: "6846499.23063543",
2007: "6837383.17387017",
2008: "6810185.26824634",
2009: "6283177.01076618",
2010: "6544487.27529572"}];

function getYearFromObjectArray(value){
  var objArrOnlySelectedYear = dumpObjectArray.filter(d => d.key === value);
  return objArrOnlySelectedYear;
};
```

Instead of filtering and returning objects with value in question I get following error notification:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
> at getYearFromObjectArray

update:
Thank you all so much for helping me better understand and hence formulate my question better. Function getYearFromObjectArray() should return all the corresponding values of keys of the dumpObjectArray. For example getYearFromObjectArray(2007) or maybe it is getYearFromObjectArray("2007") should return ["5230542.3962404","6837383.17387017"] in this case.  I need this for constructing a D3 scatterplot where the data comes from a CSV file.

Comment: and move `getYearFromObjectArray(...)` after you have defined your array

Comment: What are you trying to do? The object is `dumpObjectArray` do not have properties named `key`, so filtering on that would not work. If you want to find objects that have a key that is named the same as `value`, we have a number of questions about that.

Comment: what would `d.key` be? And `===` won't work on objects or arrays (like your parameter `value`) and you are passing somehting as parameter (and also using in the called function) that is not yet defined ...

Comment: Thank you all for your help and making me better understand. I made an update to my question so it better understandable.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you are looking for to search for the `object` that has a `value` equal to the `value` parameter.

```js
var dumpObjectArray = [{
2000: "3861703.86265837",
2001: "3948395.50088809",
2002: "4079614.75274644",
2003: "4243914.23578233",
2004: "4473182.3714518",
2005: "4666976.64129297",
2006: "4912930.11306349",
2007: "5230542.3962404",
2008: "5447541.9024238",
2009: "5614275.08094141",
2010: "5873859.25045115"},
{2000: "6445883.82450361",
2001: "6500776.94950847",
2002: "6510827.66224668",
2003: "6702943.57911293",
2004: "6732003.46639188",
2005: "6712282.82564533",
2006: "6846499.23063543",
2007: "6837383.17387017",
2008: "6810185.26824634",
2009: "6283177.01076618",
2010: "6544487.27529572"}];

function getYearFromObjectArray(value){
  return dumpObjectArray.filter(d => Object.values(d).find(i => i === value));
};

var displayedYearDataCo2 = getYearFromObjectArray("6544487.27529572");

console.log(displayedYearDataCo2)
```

Comment: Thank you Mina for your help. I made an update to my question for it to be more clear.  Applying your code i am at following, but it still does not work:                                       function getYearFromObjectArray(value){
  return dumpObjectArray.filter(d => Object.keys(d).find(i => i === value));
};

var displayedYearDataCo2 = getYearFromObjectArray(2007);

console.log(displayedYearDataCo2)